# Getting exception when trying to execute TC using Nunit with Selenium

Tags: c#, selenium, automated-tests, nunit

```
namespace NunitTCs
{
    [TestFixture]
    class Test2
    {
        IWebDriver driver;

        [SetUp]
        public void setup()
        {
            driver = new ChromeDriver();
            Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        }

        [Test]
        public void Test()
        {
            driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("http://www.google.com");            
        }
    }
}
```

When trying to run from Test Explorer getting below:

> [30-04-2018 21:41:33 Warning] Warning: Could not find source location
>   for test Unhandled. [30-04-2018 21:41:47 Error] ERROR: Test discovery
>   was cancelled after 30 s for executable
>   E:\WorkSpace\WorkSpace_VS\ConsoleApp1\NunitTCs\bin\Debug\NunitTCs.exe
>   [30-04-2018 21:41:47 Informational] Found 0 tests in executable
>   E:\WorkSpace\WorkSpace_VS\ConsoleApp1\NunitTCs\bin\Debug\NunitTCs.exe

Tried running in debug mode, its working fine. Updated the chrome also.
Please suggest the solution.

Comment: I did not see any issue with the code, I executed on my machine. Can you make sure you have installed required Nuget packages such as Nunit3TestAdapter, Selenium support etc.

Comment: I uninstalled and installed the test adapter, but still getting same issue. In debug mode without any breakpoint its executing successfully.

Comment: Why are you creating console project ? just curious. Can you try bulding Nunit project ? go to File-> New -> Project -> Test -> Nunit 3 Unit Test Project. Please provide more information so that people can help you here, as well as look here : stackoverflow.com/questions/19298347

Comment: Thanks Mike. I could not see the option to create Nunit test project when I navigated to the path. It has only unit test project. So created unit test project and its working currently.

Comment: That’s good to know, but u can have a look on the link I shared on my last comment, that would be helpful in future.